# PHP Include paths fail in https mode

Tags: php, apache2

I'm at a loss here.  I'm thinking it has to do with my apache2 virtual host configuration but I'm not sure.

I have 2 domains.  domain1.com and domain2.com.  They point to the same directory (because 90% of the pages used are the same for both sites).

Now I need one setup for SSL (domain1.com).  I thought I did everything correctly, however when I try to access a page via https:// instead of http:// it throws the 
`Failed opening required 'wsdl/DealerLookup.php'  include_path='.:/var/www/domain2.com/includes:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/domain2.com/www/home.php on line 2`

Here is the virtual server setup.

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>
    ServerAdmin admins@domain2.com
    ServerName domain2.com
    ServerAlias domain1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2.com/www
    <Directory /var/www/domain2.com/www>
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

            RewriteRule ^partner/([0-9a-zA-Z]*)$ index.php?rule=$1 [L]
            RewriteRule ^webinar/([0-9a-zA-Z]*)$ webinar.php?aid=$1 [L]
            RewriteRule ^membership/([0-9a-zA-Z]*)$ intro.php?aid=$1 [L]
            RewriteRule ^go/(0-9a-zA-Z*)$ cab.php [L]
            RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]*)$ /index.php?aid=$1 [L]


    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domain2/root/error.log
    TransferLog /var/log/apache2/domain2/root/access.log
    LogLevel warn
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/domain2/root/rewrite.log"
    php_admin_value session.cookie_domain "domain2.com"
    php_admin_flag session.cookie_secure off
    php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/domain2.com/:/usr/share/php/"
    php_value include_path ".:/var/www/domain2.com/includes:/usr/share/php"
    php_admin_flag  file_uploads off
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "/opt/ssl/domain2/domain2.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/ssl/domain2/domain2.key"
    SSLCACertificateFile "/opt/ssl/domain2/gd_bundle.crt"
    ServerAdmin admins@domain2.com
    ServerName domain1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2.com/www
    <Directory /var/www/domain2.com/www>
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

            RewriteRule ^partner/([0-9a-zA-Z]*)$ index.php?rule=$1 [L]
            RewriteRule ^webinar/([0-9a-zA-Z]*)$ webinar.php?aid=$1 [L]
            RewriteRule ^membership/([0-9a-zA-Z]*)$ intro.php?aid=$1 [L]
            RewriteRule ^go/(0-9a-zA-Z*)$ cab.php [L]
            RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]*)$ /index.php?aid=$1 [L]


    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domain2/root/error.log
    TransferLog /var/log/apache2/domain2/root/access.log
    LogLevel warn
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/domain2/root/rewrite.log"
    php_admin_value session.cookie_domain "domain2.com"
    php_admin_flag session.cookie_secure off
    php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/domain2/:/usr/share/php/"
    php_value include_path ".:/var/www/domain2.com/includes:/usr/share/php"
    php_admin_flag  file_uploads off
</VirtualHost>
```

As you can see the include_path and open_basedir are exactly the same for my non ssl and ssl.  Any idea why this is happening?